# How to check whether a combobox selection contains specific text or word

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

My combobox has 5 values, and three of them contain a particular word that, if selected, should enable two other controls on the form that would be otherwise disabled. I already figured out how to enable/disable the controls but im trying to figure out the correct syntax for the code that would check if these values are selected or not, but cannot find a clear format of code. Please help.

Comment: Where's you code that has bad syntax? Are you checking one column or multiple columns. We can't tell anything from your description

Comment: Im sorry if you dont understand my description. combobox has one column with 5 different values, 3 of which have a similar word. I want to check if any of the three are selected. I don't have any idea about the correct syntax, all I've figured out is how to enable/disable the controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your combobox only has 5 values and is limited to those 5 values, then just use the whole value and not the containing word.

```vb
private sub cmb1_AfterUpdate()
if me![cmb1].value ="value1" Or me![cmb1].value ="value2" Or me![cmb1].value ="value3" then
   me!txtbox.enabled = true
else
   me!txtbox.enabled = false
end if
end sub
```

Comment: it is limited to only those values, this is the perfect solution, works like a charm. thanks.